# How can I combine the texts with same date in the python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have the following data frame and I want to gather texts with the same date on a single date.

```
date        text
2020-09-10  text1
2020-09-10  text2
2020-09-09  text3
2020-09-09  text4
2020-09-08  text5
2020-09-08  text6
```

My expected data frame is like that.

```
date        text
2020-09-10  text1text2
2020-09-09  text3text4
2020-09-08  text5text6
```

Comment: Groupby, column, concatenate. Why would you do this? I have no idea

Comment: Try `df.groupby('date')['text'].sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.groupby('date').agg({'text':'sum'})`

```
date        text
2020-09-10  text1text2
2020-09-09  text3text4
2020-09-08  text5text6
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted. Also, it returns as a data frame.

Comment: No, that is very useful.

Comment: if this answers your question please accept the answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-09-10','2020-09-10','2020-09-09','2020-09- 
09','2020-09-08','2020-09-08'],'text':['134','13','2','3','4','5']})
df.groupby('date')['text'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and it returns as a "Series".